# What is the preferred way of returning an immutable map from a locally built mutable one?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Frequently, I find myself implementing methods that build a map from an input source. In this case, I use a `scala.collection.mutable.Map`, assuming greater speed and efficiency; however, once this collection is built, I no longer want it to be mutable.

What is the preferred Scala way of returning an immutable map from a mutable one? Usually, I do a `myMap.toMap` which obviously works, but smells. Alternatively, you can set the return type to `scala.collection.Map` which doesn't require building a new collection, but seems like it could confuse readers.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: I think using a `newBuilder` as in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079146/scala-initializing-mutable-maps-and-exposing-them-as-immutable/26081768#26081768) and then `.result` would be an equivalent solution with some style merits over defining a mutable `Map`

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to call `.toMap`.  It's short, clean, and is an explicit way of saying that you want to convert your collection to an `immutable.Map`.

I think setting the type to `scala.collection.Map` would, indeed, be confusing.  It also wouldn't protect you from someone setting the type back.  Making the type `immutable.Map` is clear and safe.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you think `.toMap` smells, but if you want to be explicit `collection.immutable.Map() ++ myMap` ought to clearly document what is going on.  (Don't forget the `()`; they're not optional.)

Simply changing the return type doesn't fully fix the immutability problem; the mutating methods are no longer visible, but the user could easily cast back.  That is the highest performance approach, though, since nothing is really changing.

Comment: After reading both yours and @dhg's responses, I agree that toMap is the best solution. I think `toMap` smelled to me because it seemed wrong to build a new collection from the existing one, when I only wanted to hide the mutable methods. (I'm dealing with very large collections.) That being said, I did forget that a client could just cast it back to the underlying mutable type, which is worse. 

Type-safe solution ftw.

Comment: @pathdependent - If speed is important, you should check to make sure that it's faster to build the mutable map and then add it to an immutable map than just to build the immutable map from scratch.  If space is important, you definitely want to favor building the immutable map from scratch so you don't need to have two maps present at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val myMap: mutable.Map[K,V] = ???
val unmodifiable: mutable.Map[K,V] =
  java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap[K,V](myMap)
val newMap = unmodifiable.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.Map[K,V]]
```

You can cast `newMap` to a `mutable.Map`, but modifications will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

In my case, the maps may be small enough that `toMap` may be faster and use less memory.