# Scala - initializing mutable Maps and exposing them as immutable

Tags: scala

Is there any "good" code pattern for a `Class` initializing and populating private mutable Maps, and then exposing them as immutable ones? Or should I just eternally regret my functional misconduct in such cases?

*In a certain Class, I am initializing some Maps as mutable ones*, as the logic for initializing them does not fit very naturally, in this one case, with a pure mutable creation approach. Or, I was just lazy to model it immutably.

Now, I get Scala ugly code - after all the initialization computation, I copy-convert the mutable Maps into immutable ones (mostly through `.toMap`). This is already ugly as (1) the code has double the Maps and the double naming feels a bit off, and (2) the conversion lines look more involved than I'd hope for.

Additionally (3), it is to my disliking that the type definitions of the resulting immutable Maps, can only reside at the bottom of the code now, as they can only be declared after the initialization computation (or, can they be defined `lazy` and move to the top? still not entirely elegant).

Any way to elegantly wrap up around mutable Maps initialization code?

Comment: Regarding (2): you can just call `toMap` on mutable Maps to get an immutable version. Can you provide a small example for your problem as a whole?

Comment: Consider using an auxiliary constructor (or companion object method) to create the final immutable data before calling the constructor. This should eliminate the need for lazy and persisting the original mutable structures - granted it is still a rebuild process and with new objects.

Comment: Anything like an immutable view or projection?

Comment: Would you be happy with using a `MapBuilder`? It will allow you to fill your map in a mutable way, then get the resulting `Map` without copying with `.result()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
scala> class X {
     |   private val mb = collection.immutable.Map.newBuilder[String, Int]
     |   def m = mb.result
     |   mb += ("a" -> 1)  // stuff
     | }
defined class X

scala> new X().m
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted, but it looks like the exact fit. The way I see it it provides the ability to build the map with the performance properties of a mutable one, and automagically exposes it as an immutable. Any downsides of any kind?

Comment: Is there similarly a builder method for other immutable collections?

Comment: @matt Someone wants to feel guilty about ugly mutability. They're probably right about that.

Comment: @matt - There are Builders for most (if not all) immutable data structures.  Also, if this answer fit your need consider accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I think using `var`s of immutables rather that `val`s of mutables, evolving the `var` collections according to my initialization logic,  can be the optimal pattern wherever applicable. No duplicate collections, no code to convert from immutable to mutable, clear type definitions at the top of the Class...

However, it is my understanding that this functional way trades-off with run time efficiency, as mutable collections can provide better modification performance when running modification logic on them while building them.

Comment: As my edit said, for Maps of a few entries, immutable can be optimal in time and space.