# Scala Return type missmatch

Tags: scala

Using this code:

```
val kv: HashMap[Int, Double] = HashMap[Int, Double]()
val temp = valuesList.list.foreach { (id: Int, value: Option[Double]) => 
  val kvValue: Double = kv.getOrElse(id, 0)
  val nvValue: Double = value.getOrElse(0)
  val nv = kvValue + nvValue
  kv.put(id, nv)
}
```

I get this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Option[Double]) => Option[Double]
 required: ((Int, Option[Double])) => ?
```

Can't seem to find the solution...

Comment: what's the point of trying to use `kv` if it's declared as empty? `getOrElse` will always return what's in the parameters since it's empty

Comment: @ElectricCoffee it's just an example? But more idiomatic is: `val kv = mutable.Map[Int, Double]()` or `val kv = mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, Double]`

Comment: @som-snytt more idiomatic would be not to use mutable data at all, and use `map` rather than `foreach` to build a collection rather than mutate one

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Even modulo Odersky endorsement of local mutability, it seems building with a mutable.Map is common. Also there are the type inference pitfalls with maps in for exprs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079146/scala-initializing-mutable-maps-and-exposing-them-as-immutable

Comment: @ElectricCoffee How else to build a hashmap? I was trying to use kv to see if the value is already set and then add the value to it, or use 0 if id is not yet present.

Comment: @MihailBurduja but why see if the value is already set, if the map doesn't contain any values? an empty map by its very definition doesn't have anything set

Comment: @ElectricCoffee it will get populated. It's checked and populated in the foreach.

Comment: @MihailBurduja yes but the whole point is, why check an empty collection for values if it's empty? wouldn't it make more sense to just create the collection rather than waste precious cycles checking if the empty collection is empty?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee it's empty at first iteration only. After the first cycle of foreach it's not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you give the wrong type of your function.

The `valuesList` is probably a list of tuple. That is, `List[(Int, Option[Double])]`.

So the `foreach` gives the tuple to your anonymous function, rather than a `Int` and a `Option`.

A quick solution is using `case` to construct a partial function which nudges compiler to unpack tuple for you.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

val kv: HashMap[Int, Double] = HashMap[Int, Double]()
val valuesList = List(1-> Option(1.0))

val temp = valuesList foreach {
  case (id: Int, value: Option[Double]) =>
    val kvValue: Double = kv.getOrElse(id, 0)
    val nvValue: Double = value.getOrElse(0)
    val nv = kvValue + nvValue
    kv.put(id, nv)
}

println(kv)
// gives Map(1 -> 1.0)
```

Make sure I changed `valuesList` here.

Comment: If you are not familiar with partial function, this is a good article about it.(http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html)

Comment: mutable data is generally considered bad practice though